# Adapting Java code(a puzzle solver) to Android

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my Java code to solve this puzzle. I have a little experience on Android. I want to transfer my code to Android. I tried but I couldn't run the code on android. Is it possible easily? How?

```
public class WordPuzzle {
   public Set<String> findWords(char[][] puzzle, Set<String> words) {
   private int findMinimumWordLength(Set<String> words) {
   private Set<String> findPossibleWords(char[][] puzzle, int minimumWordLength) {
   public WordPuzzle() {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work perfectly well as the center of the Android work. You will need to add an android user interface, which is a fair amount of work.

Can I suggest the ["Hello Android"](http://pragprog.com/titles/eband/hello-android) book which has a Sudoku puzzle UI as an example

Comment: Have any suggestion about designing an UI for this code? What kind of approach should I use?

Comment: There's just too much to put in a single answer. The book overrides the onDraw() method of the View class, and then uses methods like drawLine(), drawRect() and drawText() on the Canvas class. Maybe you should have a look at http://www.designerandroid.com/?cat=3

Comment: Thanks. I couldnt run my code on Android, could you help about this?

Comment: Not without you explaining what the problem is, no - that would clearly be impossible. "I couldn't run"?  Eh?

Comment: I'm new on android and dont know how to call my class from an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of documentation about installing Android SDK. You can start here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Comment: I'm not talking about installing SDK, talking about joining Android activities with my code.